# Animated.View and useRef are inexplicably being shared between child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am rendering a list of items like so:

```
{formattedJournal[meal].map((food, idx, arr) => {
                const isLast = idx === arr.length - 1;
                return (
                  <View key={idx}>
                    <JournalItem
                      isLast={isLast}
                      idx={idx}
                      food={food}
                    />
                  </View>
                );
              })}

// JournalItem.js
  
const translateX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current || 0;
  handleDelete = (food) => {
    Animated.timing(translateX, {
      toValue: -width,
      duration: 350,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start(() => null);
  };

return (<Swipeable
        renderRightActions={renderRightActions}
        overshootRight={false}
        onSwipeableOpen={() => handleDelete(food)}
        rightThreshold={75}
        containerStyle={[
          {
            transform: [{ translateX }],
          },
        ]}
      > ... )
```

What I want to accomplish is simple, I want to delete an item when the user swipes it. Instead, what happens is, the *last* item in the list receives the animation, no matter which element you triggered the swipe on, which makes no sense, because each `useRef` call is scoped to its own instance of `JournalItem`, so I have no idea why it's only using the last reference when swiping.

Answer (score 1):

Insidious. It was because I wasn't scoping the `handleDelete` function with `const`. Don't be lazy and omit `const`!